# CherryPy 3.2 ImportError: No module named wsgiserver3

Tags: cherrypy

I am using CherryPy 3.2 on home computer with no issues. When I run it on my work machine, I keep getting ImportError: No module named wsgiserver3.

Don't know what's going on, using python 3.1 on both machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too.  Apparently it's an issue with the build.  The site below has a copy that does have the module:

https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1110/cherrypy-322win32exe-installer-didnt